# How to make sure two azure SQL databases perform similarly?

Tags: c#, database, azure

I have two databases on Azure SQL, they are used by .net EF application. A query on one database times out, on another the same query completes immediately.

I went in and extended timeout to 180 seconds, then

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
result = db.Objects.Select(o => λ);
watch.Stop();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Database 1 responds after 66 seconds.
Database 2 responds after 0.2 seconds.

I went to query performance insight, found the query and executed it manually through VS’s SQL Server Object explorer.

Database 1 responds within 1 second.

Database 2 responds within 1 second.

Query insight on database 1 shows me the following:

```
Date: Time             CPU%    Total time      Executions count
4/11: 11 AM - 12 PM    5.8     00:08:30.340    17
4/11: 12 PM - 01 PM    8.35    00:17:55.890    12
```

So I know it’s been getting worse in the past hour. How can I influence/debug that considering that both databases belong in the same server and in the same pricing tier?

2016-04-13: Story continued

Across nearly 20 databases, this was noted in only one. The effect subsided since then, but I’ll be on the lookout.

Query addresses objects’ navigation properties and the slowdown was observed only when junction tables had additional columns (on tables which contain useful data besides just the two foreign keys).

Answer (score 0):

What region are you in? Maybe you can ask Azure Support to look into it?

In the meantime, here's a suggestion to troubleshoot: create 2 new databases and use them the same way you've been using the first 2 databases.

Are the new ones identical in performance? Or do you see any differences?

Comment: East Coast, US. In truth, I have nearly 20 databases, and noticed the effect in only one. This problem subsided, but while trying to deal with it, I also adjusted all the similar queries for increased performance.

Interesting caveat: there are 13 similar queries in the application. Each query takes data from 2 or 3 related tables (by nav props), and slowdown only happened in three queries all of which had additional columns in joint tables.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I would then suggest contacting Azure support as well. You can also find them on Twitter, under @AzureSupport so maybe you can tweet them a link to this SO question.